# How to find all rows where sum of a column in an associated model is greater than x

Tags: sequelize.js

I am new to `sequelize.js`.
I am working on a minor project using `mysql` with `sequelize.js` to store data.

I have `Member` and `Loan` models.

```
 var Member = sequelize.define('members', {
    rollNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        unique:true,
        primaryKey:true,
        unsigned:true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20)
    },
    middleName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20)
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20)
    },

    idNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        unique:true,
    },
    mobileNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20)
    }
});




 var Loan = sequelize.define('loans',{
    memberRollNumber:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: Member, key: "rollNumber" },
        allowNull: false
    },
    disbursedAmount:{
      type: Sequelize.FLOAT
    },
    interestRate:{
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT
    },

    initialBalance:{
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT
    },
    duration:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    disbursementDate:{
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
    },
    dueDate:{
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
    }
});
```

`Loan.belongsTo(Member);`

`Member.hasMany(Loan);`

Now here, I want to get all the members whose sum of `Loan.initialBalance` is greater than "1000" or any other number.

```
function getLoans(callback){
    Member.findAll({
        include: [ Loan ] ,
        where:{}
    }).then(function (members) {

        callback(members)
    })
}
```

I have spent hours trying to figure out what goes in the `where:{}` clause. Please advice on possible solutions.

Comment: You cannot filter on aggregated values in the where clause (unless aggregation happens in a subquery), you need the having clause.

Comment: @Shadow please show an example

Comment: I do not know sequelize.js, so I can't.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to do it via `group_by` and `having` , and here is how you can do that with sequelize :

```
Member.findAll({
    include : {
        model : Loan
        attributes : [],
        required : true 
    },
    group : ['members.id','loans.initial_balance'],
    having : {
        $and : [
            // condition to check sum of initialBalance is greater than 1000
            sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('initial_balance')), { $gt : 1000 }) ,
        ]
    }
})
```

> Note : Please change column name as per your DB.